# How to pull object to the left side out of the div(class "card")

Tags: html, css, getuikit

this is what i have [image]

and this is what i have to do
[image]

i know how to create "hover" but don't understand how to add this numbers which are pulled to the left OUT of the card!
this is my html

```
            <li>
                <div uk-parallax="opacity: 0,1; y: 100,0; viewport: 0.3"
                     class="uk-card uk-card-hover uk-card-small uk-card-body">
                    <h3 class="uk-card-title">HOW THE PRICE CALCULATED</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div uk-parallax="opacity: 0,1; y: 100,0; viewport: 0.5"
                     class="uk-card uk-card-hover uk-card-small uk-card-body">
                    <h3 class="uk-card-title">HOW THE PRICE CALCULATED</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
```

By the way i am using css framework named UIkit 3, maybe it can help somehow...
Thank you!

Comment: It would be great if you can add CSS for given html?

Comment: the think is that i am using css framework, so 95% of all classes are created by UIkit

Comment: in that part i didn't do anything manually in css, maybe i will...

Comment: i would use transform: translateX(0px); within the CSS file. the position will likely be a negative number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do some custom CSS, but it can be accomplished with CSS counters + before pseudo element, like so:

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: mycounter;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

li {
  counter-increment: mycounter;
  position: relative;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

li::before {
  content: counter(mycounter);
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  font-size: 72px;
}

li:hover::before {
  color: rgb(0,100,255);
  font-size: 96px;
  left: -40px;
  top: -5px;
}
```

Here it is on codepen (with a little more styling to get it closer to your mockup):

https://codepen.io/jcatt/pen/jeOQaO?editors=1100

And here's a guide to doing this kind of thing:

https://css-tricks.com/custom-list-number-styling/